# Universal cover of the pinched sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the sphere $S^2$ and identify its north and south poles to get a "pinched" sphere. What is the universal cover of this space?

Comment: Infinite chain of spheres, the south pole of the previous identified with the north pole of the next. Verify that this is simply connected, and see that the obvious covering map is indeed a covering map.

Comment: There is an actual method to do the construction of the universal covering space of any (reasonable) space in the covering spaces section in Hatcher; pretty sure they have it in many other texts, and/or websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The universal cover of this space is an infinite chain of spheres (in both directions) - one sphere for each integer - the north pole of each identified with the south pole of the next.

To verify that this is indeed the universal cover, first check that the space described is simply connected. Now consider the obvious covering map; the projection map on each sphere. Verify that this is indeed a covering map. That does it for us; the infinite chain of spheres is the universal cover of the pinched sphere.